# angular doesn't load ng-admin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-admin

I'm trying to set up a simple app with angular 1.5 and ng-admin,I imported all the dependencies and done everything right but angular can't find the ng-admin module even though I have imported it
this is my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Gestionale Clienti</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="">

        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src-="utilities/ng-admin.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="utilities/ng-admin.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css_compiled/base.css" />

    </head>
    <body ng-app="gestionale">

        <div ui-view></div>

        <script src="bundle.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

this is my javascript:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('gestionale',['ng-admin']);
```

and the error I get is : Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=gestionale&p1=Errorogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A449)
thanks in advance,any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo

```
<script src-="utilities/ng-admin.min.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script src="utilities/ng-admin.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, ng-admin currently doesn't support Angular 1.5. Use ng-admin 0.9 it with Angular 1.3, or the master branch (future 1.0) with Angular 1.4.